# Output Variable in python tinter gui not outputting value

Tags: python

I have made a program which adds up the drinks you would like to order calculated tax ect and outputs the end total. The end total however is not outputting correctly.

I am quite new and don't know if I am reading this right but I think it is making OverAllCost the total of the drinks and the tax and discount. The total then is increased by if it is takeaway or not(had to make it a float value to multiply it by 1.05) then it is assigned to the variable total. Then Total is displayed in the label.

```
costoforder = "$",str('%.2f'% (costofcappacuino +  costoflatte +   costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe))

PayTax=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee +  costofamericano + costoffrappe)*0.15)

Totalcost=(costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee  + costofamericano + costoffrappe)

Disscount=((costofcappacuino +  costoflatte + costofflatwhite + costofblackcoffee + costofamericano + costoffrappe)*0.10)

OverAllCost=int( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount) 
if OverAllCost >= 12: 
    OverAllCost="$"+str( PayTax + Totalcost - Disscount) 
else:
    OverAllCost="$"+str( PayTax + Totalcost)
Disscounts="$"+str('%.2f'% Disscount)   
PaidTax=' $%.2f' % PayTax
Total = float()
if Takeaway == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'y' or 'Y':
    OverAllCost=Total*1.05

Total = StringVar()
Disscount = StringVar()

Disscount.set(Disscounts)
cost.set(costoforder)
Tax.set(PaidTax)
Subtotal.set(costoforder)
Total.set(OverAllCost)
FinalTotal.set(Total)
FinalDiscount.set(Disscounts)

rand = StringVar()
Cappacuino = StringVar()
Latte = StringVar()
Flat_White = StringVar()
Black_Coffee = StringVar()
Subtotal = StringVar()
Total = StringVar()
Disscount = StringVar()
Frappe = StringVar()
Tax = StringVar()
cost = StringVar()
Americano = StringVar()
FinalDiscount = StringVar()
Takeaway = StringVar()
FinalTotal = StringVar()

lblTotal = Label(f1, font=( 'aria' ,16, 'bold' ),text="Total",fg="steel blue",bd=10,anchor='w')
lblTotal.grid(row=5,column=4)
txtTotal = Entry(f1,font=('ariel' ,16,'bold'), textvariable=FinalTotal , bd=6,insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue" ,justify='right')
txtTotal.grid(row=5,column=5)
```

The problem however is that it displays 'PY_VAR15' instead of the value and does not give any other error message.

Comment: Why have you created a dozen or more `StringVar`s, some of them twice, some of them replacing other variables of the same names?

Comment: I have done it because other areas of the code require those variables to be different types.

Comment: I don't really understand why you're using the Stringvariable. If a value appears in the visual interface, assigning it to a variable is nonsense. There are serious problems with your calling priority. **INIT >> BUILD >> RUN** It is the basic principle of visual application. The application looks like vegetable soup. The basic rule of the software: **No variable is left blank, you cannot provide backward control!** (`myVar.set("INN0")` I=INIT, N=None(which class/function accesed), N=None(Not an trace variable), 0=Access Conter(Zero)). I haven't any idea about of your code!